# Expression blend behavior Mix 09 pack gallery

Tags: expression-blend, behavior

I'm a designer so not to knowledgable at coding :(
I'm trying to install a behavior from the gallery on Expression. I've tried this way
http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/b32dd55e-c592-4378-8153-744ccf0526ac/
but it doesn't seem to work.
Basicly I downloaded http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/MIXBehaviorPack
ran the project in Blend, dragged the dll files into C:\Program Files\Microsoft Expression\Blend 3\Libraries\Silverlight\v3.0 and
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Expression\Blend 3\Libraries\WPF\v3.5
I then opened up Blend again, rebuilt project and the behaviors didn't appear, I even tried adding them as a reference by right clicking my project in the projects panel.

Is there an easier way to install these behaviors. What am I missing out?

Thanks
Judi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That set of behaviors was built for the beta version of Silverlight 3.  Go get the new pack (though the physics behaviors aren't there yet):

http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/

There is an installer that does all the hard word of installing them.